# Overriding a nested class functions or use delegates?**

Tags: c#, class, oop, nested

I have a `base class` which has a nested type, inside. There's a function in the outer (base) type which would be overridden by it's children later. In fact this function belongs to the `inner type` from the `OO` prespective but still I need it, to be overridden by `subtypes` of the `base class`.

Should I use this function as a `callback` from the `inner type` or just move it inside the `inner type` and let's the `subtypes` to override it from there?

**EDIT:** Sample code added

```
class A
{
    protected void func() { /* do something */ }
    class B { /**/ }
}

// OR

class A
{
    class B
    {
        protected void func() { /* do something */ }
    }
}

// Then

class C : A
{
    override func() { /**/ }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to illustrate it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to crate a delegate for the *inner type* function which is initiated by the constructor of the *base class*:

```
internal class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(Action myAction)
    {
        this.innerType = new InnerType(myAction);
    }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        // When no function delegate is supplied, InnerType should default to
        // using its own implementation of the specific function
        this.innerType = new InnerType();
    }
}
```

As you see, deriving types can call the base constructor with `:base (overridenAction)` where they can provide their own implementation of the function right to the innermost type. Of course, you are not obligated to use `Action` but any delegate you want.

Answer (score 1):

IMO what you are describing looks like [The Strategy design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). Consider using this pattern. Your code would be much more maintainable as it contains well recognizable pattern. You also can take a look at [state design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state), usually you have to choose between these two, they are closely connected.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario:

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
        protected void func() { // do something }
    }
}
```

You cannot derive from class `A` and override `func()` in class `B`.

From your description it seems that A-derived classes should be able to override some function (or functionality) in the inner class `B` which indicates that you maybe should rethink your design. Either extract `B` and don't make it an inner class or make the functionality you want to override an explicit dependency via an interface like this:

```
class A
{
    private B _MyB;
    public A(ISomeBehaviour behaviour)
    {
        _MyB = new B(behaviour);
    }
}
```

In anyway if you want to stick with your design then I would not recommend the delegate approach and rather choose the override because with the delegates it makes it harder to add decoration if that is all you need in your child classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the outer class can serve as a strategy to the inner service class.

Note that using pattern names such as `TemplateMethod` and `Strategy` as real class names is not recommended, use whatever is meaningful in the domain. Same applies to `Outer` and `Inner`.

```
public class Consumer
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        IOuterFoo fooService = new Derived();
        fooService.OuterFoo();
    }
}

// ...

public interface IOuterFoo
{
    void OuterFoo();
}

abstract class Base : Base.IStrategy, IOuterFoo
{
    public void OuterFoo() { _service.Foo(); }

    private readonly InnerService _service;

    protected Base() { _service = new InnerService(this); }

    private interface IStrategy { void Foo(); }

    private class InnerService
    {
        private readonly IStrategy _strategy;
        public InnerService(IStrategy strategy) { _strategy = strategy; }
        public void Foo() { _strategy.Foo(); }
    }

    void IStrategy.Foo() { TemplateMethodFoo(); }

    protected abstract void TemplateMethodFoo();
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void TemplateMethodFoo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It always bugs me when I see >10 LoC code samples with names like `Foo`, `Bar`, or worse, `OuterFoo` and pattern names like `IStrategy`. I understand that you did this to make example general and illustrate the pattern, however to me it would be ten times better readable if it demonstrated solving some real-world problem, no matter how farfetched or simplified.